# Getting index of median value in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, indexing, median

When searching for `min` or `max` value one can get the index of the found value like that:

```
[val, index] = max(some_array_of_values);
```

How to get the index of `median` value?

**NOTE:**
Yes, I know what median is and I know it sometimes can be average of two values at the middle. What I want to get is the index of value nearest or equal to median value.
The array of values contain unsorted values. 
We cannot sort this array - I need the index from the original array. But of course we can sort a copy of it. There are no limitations due to size of the array - it is relatively small (about 100 values)

Answer (score 5):

The idea is to sort the vector, and take the middle value. For even-length vectors, we compute the average of the two values in the middle.

Example:

```
%# some random vector
%#x = rand(99,1);        %# odd-length
x = rand(100,1);         %# even-length

%# index/indices for median value
num = numel(x);
[~,ord] = sort(x);
idx = ord(floor(num/2)+(rem(num,2)==0):floor(num/2)+1);

%# median value
med = mean( x(idx) );

%# compare against MATLAB's function
median(x)
```

---

#### EDIT

Here is a sample function implementation:

```
function [med idx] = mymedian(x)
    %# MYMEDIAN
    %#
    %# Input:   x        vector
    %# Output:  med      median value
    %# Output:  idx      corresponding index
    %#
    %# Note: If vector has even length, idx contains two indices
    %# (their average is the median value)
    %#
    %# Example:
    %#    x = rand(100,1);
    %#    [med idx] = mymedian(x)
    %#    median(x)
    %#
    %# Example:
    %#    x = rand(99,1);
    %#    [med idx] = mymedian(x)
    %#    median(x)
    %#
    %# See also: median
    %#

    assert(isvector(x));
    [~,ord] = sort(x);
    num = numel(x);

    if rem(num,2)==0
        %# even
        idx = ord(floor(num/2):floor(num/2)+1);
        med = mean( x(idx) );
    else
        %# odd
        idx = ord(floor(num/2)+1);
        med = x(idx);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

For sets which include the median, you can use find and median.

```
 a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
 find(a == median(a))
```

For sets which don't include their median, you need to get clever. We first find the smallest index which is larger than the median and the largest index which is smaller than the median. Here, of course, I assume that the set is sorted. It makes everything easier.

```
 b = [1, 2, 3, 4]
 (min(find(b>median(b))) + max(find(b<median(b)))) / 2
```

The latter solution should work in both cases. Observe that the index for a non-existent median is not a proper index at all and you should use the value accordingly (for whatever you might want to do with it).

Comment: The set is not sorted. If it was sorted I would do it on my own :)

Comment: Can't you sort the set? Then I'd first try looking for the median by using find(b == median(b)) and checking for length() == 0 (that is, is the median included in the set). If this is the case, you can get the positions of values outlying the median by using min(find(b > median(b))) and max(find(b < median(b))). What else would you like to find?

Comment: Thanks for your help, basing on your answer I found the solution on my own. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

One way to go about this problem is to subtract the median and find the minimum of the absolute values of the resulting vector:

```
[val, index] = min(abs(some_array_of_values - median(some_array_of_values)));
```

You would get the closest value to the median as a result.

This should work for finding any index of a value closest to a value_of_interest.

```
[val, index] = min(abs(some_array_of_values - value_of_interest));
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found some solution on my own.

Firstly I sort the values in my vector `D`

```
S = sort(D)
```

Then I search for the first element that is greater than or equal to median

```
idS = find(S >= median(S),1)
```

now I can get the exact value of that element and try to find it in original vector:

```
idMed = find(D == S(idS))
```

Comment: This is not an answer to the question as stated.  You said the array couldn't be sorted.

Comment: See my answer below, which avoids the sort.

Comment: @John, and I am not sorting the array. It is left intact. I'm sorting some temporary, copied array S

Comment: @Gacek, that's not usually what's meant by "We cannot sort this array."

Comment: @John, probably you're right. And probably if you had any doubts you should ask what does it exactly mean. I updated my question to make it clear. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: `idS = find(S >= median(S),1)` is always going to find the element in the middle of the array, or the one after if it’s an even-sized array. There is no need to compute the median, just do `idS = ceil((numel(S)+1)/2)`. And if you keep the second output of `sort`, you don’t need the second `find` either. But then you have Amro’s answer, which is the best one here.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to get is the index of value nearest or equal to median
>   value. The array of values contain unsorted values. We cannot sort
>   this array.

You're looking for a fast [selection algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm).  You most likely won't be able to beat the performance of built-in Matlab functions like `sort` and `median` (which is reported to use `sort` internally) by writing code in Matlab itself, since that will involve slow loops.  Instead, if you really need something more efficient than those solutions, you will have to implement your own in a compiled language.

[`nth_element`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29453-nthelement) from the Mathworks file exchange includes a mex interface to the C++ standard library function `std::nth_element` and includes a special purpose `fast_median` function--this might be a good example to start from.  You would have to modify this to keep track of the array indicies.

Answer (score -1):

Since the array can't be sorted, (presumably because it's so large), and because the question is ill posed (what to do in the case of an odd number of elements in the array) just do the following:

```
ixMedian = function(v)

if (mod(numel(v),2) == 1)
   vtemp = v(1:end-1);
else
   vtemp = v;
end

ixMedian = find(vtemp == median(vtemp))
```

In the case of an odd number of elements, it returns the median.  In the case of an even number of elements, it returns one of the 4 elements closest to the median.  If the elements are distributed uniformly, and if there are 2N of them, with probability 1/N it returns one of the 2 elements closest to the median.

Comment: Curious why the two down votes for this?  It answers the question exactly with no sorting of anything.

Comment: The function `median` needs to sort the data, so trying to avoid the sort is rather pointless.